# avoid inertia scrollviewer for negative offset Windows 8 App

Tags: offset, scrollviewer

i would like to know how can i remove the inertia effect of the scrollviewer content when the offset is negative.
In reality the offset is 0.0, but the content moves in negative like a spring.

This is a video that show the effect that i'd like to remove:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kXce-VK--4&feature=youtu.be

The code is very simple:

```
<ScrollViewer  x:Name="CalendarScrollViewer" 
                           VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                           HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                           Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" 
                           ZoomMode="Disabled" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                           LayoutUpdated="CalendarScrollViewer_LayoutUpdated"  >
                        <Grid>
                          ... 
                        </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set ScrollViewer.IsScrollInertiaEnabled="False" ?